# Stripes 1.5 - any way to ask the system for a list of all ActionBeans?

Tags: java, api, stripes

I'm building an application where I have my default webpage as 'index.jsp' which consists of a list of `<stripes:link...>` tags, to link out to my various actionBeans (to their defaulthandlers).

As my application evolves and gathers more actionBeans I'm going back and adding in a new link to them : is there a way to automate this - considering that the stripes framework (I believe) iterates through all the actionBeans when it loads up - is there a way to ask the framework for this information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ActionResolver`](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/controller/ActionResolver.html) interface has several methods you could use, including [`getActionBeanClasses()`](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/controller/ActionResolver.html#getActionBeanClasses%28%29)

[`StripesFilter.getConfiguration()`](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/controller/StripesFilter.html#getConfiguration%28%29) lets you access the configuration object (and hence the `ActionResolver`) in a static way.

Here's how to do it:

```
StripesFilter.getConfiguration().getActionResolver().getActionBeanClasses()
```

Comment: Thanks for this - looks like it might work. I guess it could be decent enhancement for a future version of stripes : perhaps annotating particular actionBeans so that they 'showup' with a special tag which could be placed on the initial JSP..gonna leave this as unanswered for a bit, in case somebody else chips in with another trick to get at the Configuration...

Comment: @monojohnny I found a much simpler way (see my edited answer)