# How to get all actionbean classes at contextInitialized()

Tags: java, stripes

A similar question is answered here: [Stripes 1.5 - any way to ask the system for a list of all ActionBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605196/stripes-1-5-any-way-to-ask-the-system-for-a-list-of-all-actionbeans.But) it seems only work in an actionbean code, i.e: when it actually receives a request.

What I want is to list all actionbeans in contextListener code, for instance contextInitialized() function. Error happened:

```
net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesRuntimeException: Something is trying to access the current Stripes configuration but the current request was never routed through the StripesFilter! As a result the appropriate Configuration object cannot be located. Please take a look at the exact URL in your browser's address bar and ensure that any requests to that URL will be filtered through the StripesFilter according to the filter mappings in your web.xml.
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.getConfiguration(StripesFilter.java:160)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.util.CryptoUtil.encrypt(CryptoUtil.java:123)
```

My purpose is to automatically initialize all the plug-in classes added later, without maintaining a list of all actionbeans somewhere in the code.
Any suggestion? (or, at least, is it possible to do so?) 
Best Regards,

Comment: What is this: _My purpose is to automatically initialize all the plug-in classes added later, without maintaining a list of all actionbeans somewhere in the code_

Comment: Hi, let me explain it further. We want to separate the webapp into 2 types of functions: core functions and plug-in functions. The plug-in functions won't be bundled in the WAR. Instead, they are provided by additional JARs. Whenever we want to add new plug-in function, we just need to put a JAR into webapp/classes/lib in Web Container directory, then reload the app. Because of this, we need a way to automatically scan all the action beans, and do proper actions if an action bean is plug-in type. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you should probably put your solution as an answer and accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. After a while, I figured out the solution: using Stripes ResolverUtil

```
ResolverUtil<ActionBean> resolver = new ResolverUtil<ActionBean>();
resolver.findImplementations(ActionBean.class, "my.base.package");
Set<Class<? extends ActionBean>> beans = resolver.getClasses();
```

Thanks!